# Javascript Timer run forward after expired

Tags: javascript, html

First, I have to apologize, because I'm not familiar with Javascript. I found a JS Fiddle from someone else and adapted the code somehow. Now I have 3 questions.

1. How do I get the watch to keep running after expired? It should then display Runs since "0 days 3 hours 2 minutes 20 seconds." All I care about is that time goes on. I can adapt the text myself.
2. Always display two digits. So 02 minutes 01 seconds
3. I simply transferred the times to the span #hours / #days / #seconds. How can I take a classe instead of an id?

My custom code:

```js
CountDownTimer('12/23/2019 0:00 AM');

function CountDownTimer(date) {
     var end = new Date(date);

     var _second = 1000;
     var _minute = _second * 60;
     var _hour = _minute * 60;
     var _day = _hour * 24;
     var timer;

     function showRemaining() {
         var now = new Date();
         var distance = end - now;
         if (distance < 0) {

             clearInterval(timer);

         /* I Know, that i have no (id), because i have not declared it. 
            But i dont wanna have a text with "expired". 
            The timer should count  till ✓ Check! 
            and after reached the date -> 
            count since: 0 day, 0 hours 10 Minuten 30 Sekunden.  */

             document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

             return;
         }
         var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
         var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
         var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
         var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

         document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days; 
         document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours; 
         document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes; 
         document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds; 
     }

     timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
 }
```

```css
#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
 font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}

.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="clockdiv"><div>
   <span id="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Tage</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Stunden</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minuten</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span id="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Sekunden</div>
  </div></div>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jxdumk39/3/

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are trying to get to the element by the id `countdown` - but you don't have any such element in your html.

Comment: Thank You! I removed it. i hope correctly.

             document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';should remove, cause i dont need it.

Comment: When the clock expires your problem is with this `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';` the variable `id` you are trying to use in the `.getElementById()` selector is undefined. What element are you expecting to display the text *"EXPIRED!"*?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. Call `CountDownTimer()` recursively.

**Change:**

```
clearInterval(timer);
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
```

**To:**

```
clearInterval(timer);
CountDownTimer(...);
```

2. Convert the Number type to a string and add the leading zero if required:

**Change:**

```
 var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
```

**To:**

```
var temp = Math.floor(distance / _day);
var days = (temp.toString().length === 1)? '0' + temp : temp;
```

3. There is nothing wrong with your solution.

Comment: Thank You. I will try today